JUCE Audio Plugins On MacOS - Apple Notarization
I am currently developing an audio plugin using the JUCE Framework and have hit a bit of a snag. My audio plugin works as a standalone app, but when I try to load the VST3 or AU in Ableton it refuses to load. When I rescan plugins, it shows the name of my plugin in the status bar but never actually shows it. I am assuming it has to do with something about signing/security since I was able to load the AU in Garage Band after being prompted to lower the security requirements. The VST3 and AU both are signed with codesign and notarized with notarytool. However, when I use spctl to check if Gateway likes it, I get the message "rejected (the code is valid but does not seem to be an app)". I am guessing this may be why Ableton refuses to load my plugin.
I have searched far and wide looking for the solution to my problem but I am truly stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
